# Merge dicts use dict1 values with dict2 values

Tags: python, dictionary, join, merge

I have two dicts like this:

```
a = {'SITE1': [700], 'SITE2': [500]}
b = {'SITE1': [1,2,3,4], 'SITE2': [4,5,6,7], 'SITE3': [8,9,10,11]}
```

and I am looking for this result:

```
c = {'SITE1': [1/700, 2/700, 3/700, 4/700],
     'SITE2': [4/500, 5/500, 6/500, 7/500]}
     'SITE3': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

If a dict 'b' site is not found in 'a' dict, the values of that site should be replace by zero in the result.

Can you help me please?, thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with `1/700`? A string, 1 divided by 700?

Comment: All the elements are digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe that will do - assuming you want the values of c as lists of floats and assuming that a's values are always one-element lists...:

```
a = {'SITE1': [700], 'SITE2': [500]}
b = {'SITE1': [1,2,3,4], 'SITE2': [4,5,6,7], 'SITE3': [8,9,10,11]}

c = dict()
for key in b:
    if key in a:
        c[key] = [float(v)/(a[key][0]) for v in b[key]]
    else:
        c[key] = [0 for v in b[key]]
```

Comment: Yes, the number of values for Site in 'a' dict and in 'b' dict are always the same. One for 'a' sites and four for 'b' sites. But the number of sites in both dict can be different.

Comment: ok, so what should happen with the extra sites? ignore them if they are not present in both dictionaries?

Comment: and where can be the extra sites? only in b, or also in a?

Comment: The extra sites are always in b dict

Comment: Thanks a lot noamgot!

Answer (score 0):

```
c = { k : [ val_b / a[k][0] for val_b in b[k] ] for k in a }
```

Note that I'm assuming that with `1/700` you mean the actual result of the division.
I'm also assuming that both dictionaries always have exactly the same keys.

**EDIT**: Just noticed that in your example the first dict also stores the value in a one-element list

Comment: `for val-b in`??

Comment: Sorry, that as a typo

Comment: How did that typo not get caught by your testing?

Comment: WillemVanOnsem see the edit I made. 
@StefanPochmann retyping the code instead of copy-pasting it from the console window.